# How to pass data from Javascript page to Controller to MySQL DB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

This is my first time posting here! I am stuck trying to figure out how to retrieve data from a js script and then pass it to the controller to add it to my database or update my database? I found this seatmap JS plugin online

I am currently using a MySQL database, and MyBatis for ORM. No one in our team can seem to figure out how to make this ajax call work in a way where after clicking the buy button, then the ajax call must somehow send the data to the controller then to our database.

Can someone please help?

EDIT: 
I am using Spring MVC. I tried to @Requestparam with the controller method and I kept getting an error with "required string parameter does not exist".
The issue is that I do not know how to pass the 'selected seats' and corresponding variables to the controller when the submit button is clicked

```
<script>
var price = 7; //price

$(document).ready(function() {
var $cart = $('#selected-seats'), //Sitting Area
$counter = $('#counter'), //count of seats
$total = $('#total'); //Total money

var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
    map: [
            'aaaaa',
            'aaaaa',
            '_____',
            'aaaaa',
            'aaaaa',
            '_____',
            'aaaaa',
            'aaaaa',
            'aaaaa',
        ],
    naming : {
        top : false,
        getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
            return column;
        }
    },
    legend : { //Definition legend
        node : $('#legend'),
        items : [
            [ 'a', 'available',   'Available' ],
            [ 'a', 'unavailable', 'Sold']
        ]                   
    },

    click: function () { //Click event
        if (this.status() == 'available') { //optional seat
            $('<li>Row '+(this.settings.row+1)+' Seat '+this.settings.label+'</li>')
                .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                .appendTo($cart);

            $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
            $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+price);

            return 'selected';
        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked
                //Update Number
                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                //update totalnum
                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-price);

                //Delete reservation
                $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
                //optional
                return 'available';
        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') { //sold
            return 'unavailable';
        } else {
            return this.style();
        }

        $.ajax({
                url : $("Seatmap").attr("action"),
                data: data,
                type: "GET",

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },

                error:function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });




    }


});
//sold seat
sc.get(['1_2', '4_4','4_5','6_6','6_7','8_5','8_6','8_7','8_8', '10_1', '10_2']).status('unavailable');

});
//sum total money
function recalculateTotal(sc) {
var total = 0;
sc.find('selected').each(function () {
    total += price;
});

return total;
}
```

Comment: Is the problem on the server side? If so, that code will be more helpful. If the problem is on client side, explain what the problem is. Does the request get sent, is it incomplete?

Comment: @miken32 I edited the question to give more information